Add compile option from dependency to the whole project
My project A depends on B and C. B and C are included in A through FetchContent.
Project B contains compiled libraries that require the whole project to be compiled with:
    add_compile_options(
        $<$<CONFIG:>:/MT>
        $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/MTd>
        $<$<CONFIG:Release>:/MT>)

That means that project A and project C must be compiled with these options as well.
Therefore, if I use target_compile_options on targets from B, it doesn't work.
For now, it works if I set this in A. But I have other projects that depend on B. So it would seem better to me to set something in B instead of A.
What is the right thing to do here?

"Therefore, if I use target_compile_options on targets from B, it doesn't work." - What is exactly not working when use target_compile_options(B PUBLIC ...)? If A links with B, then all specified options are propagated to the A.

C is not compiled with these options in this case, while it needs to

Ah, I see. CMake has only mechanisms for propagate options from dependent library to the dependee (from B to A if A links with B). It has no mechanism for propagate options in reverse direction (from A to C if A links with C).

BTW, concerning specifically /MT and similar options, you are better to use MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY target property or CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY variable. E.g. you could set CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY variable at the top of A project, so it will be used in B and C automatically (Unless those projects redefine the variable, in which case CMake could report the error about incompatible options in libraries linked together.)
